# IE compatibility issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am getting following eror in IE:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'block'.

My jQuery snippet is :

```
showProcessingMessageAndBlockForm: function ()
{
    $("#checkoutContentPanel").block({ message: ACC.common.processingMessage });
}
```

It's working fine on other browsers.

Comment: could it be that jquery gets loaded after blockui was loaded? did you check the network logs?

Comment: Press F12 to open IE's Developer tools, go to the 'Script' tab and check the drop-down to see which scripts have been loaded in. Check that JQuery has been loaded in. If it is there, also try using the Console to type in some simply JQuery commands to see if other JQuery commands work. That way you can eliminate the possibility of the JQuery library not being correctly loaded. Update us with any findings by updating your question. Provide as much detail as you can on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To test if your issue is coming from your script path, try to include the script using:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script>
      /*if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "7.0"){ 
      $.blockUI();
      $('.blockOverlay').attr('Browser check','some text').click($.unblockUI);
      }*/
      $('#MyDiv').blockUI({ 
                message: '<h1>This has been blocked!</h1>', 
                css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
      });
</script>
```

The problem was when including the jquery.blockUI plugin. including it in the page but finally I have had to include it in the master page.